# API documentation - How to give response schema using rabl with grape-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, grape-api, grape-entity

We are using [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) for APIs and [grape-rabl](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-rabl) for responses in our Rails application. Now we are in the process of documenting the APIs, and we use [grape-swagger](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-swagger) for it. But we do not know how to document the response schema for the API endpoints. The tutorial of **grape-swagger** provides a way to document the responses, but only when using [grape-entity](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-entity). How can I generate docs when using **grape-rabl**?